# Force Google Colab to use python 3 in boost.python library

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, boost-python

I try to compile external library using Google Colab, but I encounter an error
`ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.65.1: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type`
I know, that is a problem with Python 2.7, but I cannot figure, how can I force Google Colab to compile my library with Python 3.x instead of 2.x. Can somebody encounter similar problem?

Comment: Try this https://www.onooks.com/how-to-change-the-python-version-used-on-google-colab/

Comment: There is only info, that someone has a problem with changing default python instance on colab, but without resolution. That doesn't help.